# The different between returning an object and response return?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Assume I have two actions methods `action1` and `action2`:

**Action1:**

```
    public JavaScriptSerializer action1() 
    {
        var student = new Student() { First = "john", Last = "doe" };
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonStudent = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jsonStudent.Serialize(student);

        return jsonStudent;

    }
```

**Action2:**

```
   public void action2()
    {
        var student = new Student() { First = "john", Last = "doe" };
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonStudent = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jsonStudent.Serialize(student);

        Response.Write(jsonStudent);
    }
```

Assume my view has a `Ajax` call like this:

```
 <script>
     $(function () {

         $.ajax({
             url: 'AjaxCallsTest/action1',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (response) {
               //code here
             },
             error: function (response, status, xhr) {
        //code here
             }


         })
     })
 </script>
```

In the two cases one was written to `Response` object and the other has a `return` statement. my question even when there is a `return`, does it actually adds the `jsonStudent` object to the `Response` object if so writing action methods with `return` statements are meaningless?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Write()` actually writes something to the client (the aspx document). It works like PHP's `echo` - it just prints to the response.

`return`, on the other hand, just returns a value to the caller function. So, if you want it to be printed (like `action2()`), you would have to print the result.

Basically, here is how you would use each of those functions to just print the `JavaScriptSerializer`:

**Action1**

```
JavaScriptSerializer a = action1();
Response.Write(a);
```

**Action2**

```
action2();
```

So, the answer to your question is, that if you don't need the `JavaScriptSerializer` object in the code later, the `return` is unecessary. But if you will use that object later, you better return it and store it.

Comment: what the difference between writing to the Response's outputStream and printing to Response via Response.Write()?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, but that one might help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETResponseWriteAndResponseOutputWriteKnowTheDifference.aspx